# Yet another .gitignore not ignoring .angular/cache entry

Tags: angular, gitignore

So I have looked at all the answers relating to the .angular/cache folder not being ignored when pushing a project to a remote repo. I have created a new project with Angular 14.

Here is my .gitignore file in root of the project (just part of the ignore file, this is the last entry in the file).

```
# Angular
/.angular
```

here is a screen shot of my project showing that the .angular folder is greyed out, which I am assuming means the folder is being ignored by git.
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfGjc.png)

I have run the following commands:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m ".gitignore is now working"
```

I have tried different entries in the .gitignore file

```
.angular/cache
/.angular/cache
.angular
.angular/
.angular/*
```

I have tried removing from cache the .angular folder specifically

```
Massimos-MBP:paradolia-admin skypirate$ git rm -r --cached /.angular
fatal: /.angular: '/.angular' is outside repository at '/Users/skypirate/Projects/paradolia-admin'
```

or this

```
Massimos-MBP:paradolia-admin skypirate$ git rm -r --cached .angular
fatal: pathspec '.angular' did not match any files
```

I double checked and the folder .angular is definitely in the project folder root.

I have even tried removing the .angular folder completely from the project.

No matter what I try I get the following error when I run:

```
git push -u origin main
```

```
Massimos-MBP:paradolia-admin skypirate$ git push -u origin main
Enumerating objects: 1691, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1691/1691), done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1667/1667), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1691/1691), 66.38 MiB | 2.30 MiB/s, done.
Total 1691 (delta 274), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (274/274), done.
remote: warning: File .angular/cache/15.0.2/angular-webpack/54656bafcc60881502aad32eb4a45285fa9bc9e6/1.pack is 98.46 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 2fb04feb3b57a0caa4fd663ff04799796e001b6a7a7b055a5f6ed0120d4bbf0f
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File .angular/cache/15.0.2/angular-webpack/e3ac25d47496cbc2f9e3adbe205cac2ccb01848d/0.pack is 285.25 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File .angular/cache/15.0.2/angular-webpack/54656bafcc60881502aad32eb4a45285fa9bc9e6/0.pack is 112.29 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/Bluemax86/paradolia-admin.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Bluemax86/paradolia-admin.git'
```

Is there a path specified somewhere that tells git which .angular folder to look at?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In a created angular application, per default `/.angular/cache` is written in the `.gitignore`. This does not work?

Comment: No unfortunately the default entry did not work for my project.

Comment: I should have thought of this previously. I removed the .git folder from my project. Reset git, initialized the project to point to the github repo, performed an initial commit, etc etc. Now everything is working fine. Must have been a glitch in the .git setup.