# Why is the .angular folder not included in the .gitignore file by default in an angular project?

Tags: angular, git, gitignore

When I created a new Angular and ASP.Net project in visual studio I see the following .gitignore added within the ClientApp that does not include .angular

I've found a couple of articles online as well as SO questions

- [Yet another .gitignore not ignoring .angular/cache entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996394/yet-another-gitignore-not-ignoring-angular-cache-entry)

I understand the reasoning behind adding .angular/cache to .gitignore. However I want to understand why it isn't included by default by the angular team?

Reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/.gitignore

In React for example the `.node_modules` folder is generally part of the .gitignore file generated by default. I'm wondering if the same could be done in angular where the `.angular` folder could be ignored from tracking by version control. Wouldn't this keep the repository sizes smaller and easier to manage?

Comment: `.angular/cache` should be there though, which has the cached files (lots of them). Is it added already?

Answer (score 0):

The `.angular` folder is not included in the `.gitignore` file by default in an Angular project because it contains essential configuration files required for the Angular CLI to function correctly. These files are necessary for the project's build process, testing, and other development tools. Excluding the `.angular` folder from the `.gitignore` file would prevent these crucial configuration files from being tracked by Git, potentially causing issues for other developers working on the project. It is generally recommended to avoid modifying the `.gitignore` file unless there are specific files or patterns that are genuinely unnecessary for the project's development and deployment.